Как узнать адрес кошелька который подключил пользователь Ton Connect
Добавил в свое web app приложение в telegram Подключение кошелька через Ton Connect UI, но не понимаю как можно взять подключенный кошелек пользователем, в консоли данные отображаются но по факту взять их нельзя, если пытаюсь взять выводит null
Код:
const tonConnectUI = new TON_CONNECT_UI.TonConnectUI({
        manifestUrl: 'https://wep-app/tonconnect-manifest.json',
        buttonRootId: 'ton-connect'
    });
    console.log(tonConnectUI);

